# Ubuntu 18.04 netplan issues: VM with 2 interfaces with static IP addressing will not configure the interfaces on boot

Tags: networking, qemu, netplan

I have a VM with two interfaces that are configured statically. For this I have an `/etc/netplan/config.yaml` file like this:

```
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        ens3:
            dhcp4: false
            addresses:
                - 10.0.1.1/16
            nameservers: [ 8.8.8.8 ]
            gateway4: 10.0.0.1
        ens4:
            dhcp4: false
            addresses:
                - 10.1.1.1/16
```

When I boot the VM, the interfaces will not come up until I log into the VM and run `sudo netplan apply` manually. I was expecting the interfaces to be configured on boot.
It works however if I set `dhcp4: true` for one of the interfaces.

Comment: You should split this question in two, this site is aimed at answering single questions.

Comment: In the first case: `sudo netplan apply` alters config files. Can you find out which ones?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I don't see any actual questions in your question posts. You describe two situations but leave your readers guessing at what you want to achieve. Could you please [edit] your post to clarify? Thanks.

Comment: is there an `/etc/netplan/50-cloud.init.yaml`or similar in the folder at all?  If there is, remove it and then try.

Answer (score 0):

i solve it with 2 different files:
on this:
[Ubuntu 18.04.1 netplan metric priority](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1068243/ubuntu-18-04-1-netplan-metric-priority)

yaml files:

```
01-netcfg.yaml
network:
 version: 2
 renderer: networkd
 ethernets:
   epn0s3:
     dhcp4: no
     dhcp6: no
     addresses: [192.168.1.194/24]
     gateway4: 192.168.1.1
     nameservers:
       addresses: [192.168.2.2]
```

backup

```
02-netcfg.yaml
network:
 version: 2
 renderer: networkd
 ethernets:
   epn0s8:
     dhcp4: no
     dhcp6: no
     addresses: [192.168.50.115/24]
     gateway4: 192.168.50.1
     nameservers:
       addresses: [192.168.50.1]
```

but the problem is around: Redundant systems and Failover.

**once the connection to port 1 and 2 is working individually, I have not managed to make it fall; loses connectivity to the internet or does not resolve the names; connect via port 2.**